# altering requests with two rewrite rules

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

So my webserver is serving up files like file_name.php. I want to make it so requests for file-name.php gets transparently redirected to file_name.php and that requests for file_name.php get explicitly redirected via a 301 redirect to file-name.php.

ie. you request file_name.php and you get 301 redirected to file-name.php which transparently loads file_name.php instead.

Unfortunately, the .htaccess file I've written to accomplish this isn't working. Here it is:

```
# make it so files with slashes that don't exist transparently redirect to files with underscores
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^-]*)-([^-]*)$ $1_$2
RewriteRule ^([^-]*)-([^-]*)-([^-]*)$ $1_$2_$3

# make it so files with underscores that do exist explicitely redirect to files with slashes
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^([^_]*)_([^_]*)$ /$1-$2 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^([^_]*)_([^_]*)_([^_]*)$ /$1-$2-$3 [L,R=301]
```

On their own they work but together it results in an infinite loop.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was really an interesting problem.

Code that I'm suggesting is **a generic recursion based code** that will translate each `_` by `-` in URL externally (no matter how many underscore are there). While internally it will do the reverse translation and load the actual URL.

```
# Only single underscore do an external 301 redirect
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+([^_]+)_([^_\s]*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1-%2 [R=301,L]

# Recursively translate each _ to - in URL and do external 302 redirect
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+([^_]+)_([^\s]*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1-%2 [R,L]

# Recursively translate - to _ to load actual URL internally
RewriteRule ^([^-]+)-(.*)$ /$1_$2 [L]
```

Comment: I like your solution! I went ahead and added `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` to that third `RewriteRule` so that if a file with dashes already exists it won't be redirected internally. Thanks!

Comment: Yes that condition will be handy.

Comment: Why are you doing 301 redirects for one _ but 302 redirects if there are more than one _?

Comment: 301's are all locally cached in all browsers so I just wanted to avoid too many 301 mappings until only one is left. Even if you change all of them to `R=301` solution will still work.

Answer (score 1):

Because the URI gets rewritten then plugged back into the rewrite engine, you'd get a redirect loop. You have to externally redirect by matching against the request and not the URI. Also, rewrite conditions only apply to the immediately following rewrite rule, so you need to duplicate them for each of your rules:

```
# make it so files with slashes that don't exist transparently redirect to files with underscores
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^-]*)-([^-]*)$ $1_$2 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^-]*)-([^-]*)-([^-]*)$ $1_$2_$3 [L]

# make it so files with underscores that do exist explicitely redirect to files with slashes
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^_]*)_([^_]*)_([^_\ \?]*)
RewriteRule ^ /%1-%2-%3 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^_]*)_([^_\ \?]*)
RewriteRule ^ /%1-%2 [L,R=301]
```